# move_uploaded_file() Unable to move using yii framework

Tags: frameworks, yii

i'm trying to upload file with yii framework when this error appears

> move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move '/tmp/phpLEdRdu' to 'http://wmtunisia.com/tamtamtravel.tn/upload/2013-05-03entry_3.jpg'

and this what i'm doing in controller

```
public function actionCreate()

{

    $model=new Voitures;

    if(isset($_POST['Voitures']))

    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Voitures'];
        $model->image=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'image');

        if($model->validate())

        {

            if(!empty($model->image)){

                $rep = Yii::app()->params['webroot'].'upload/';



                $model->image->saveAs($rep.date('Y-m-d').$model->image);


                $model->image=date('Y-m-d').$model->image;

            }

            $model->description= CHtml::encode($_POST['Voitures']['description']);
            $model->save();

            Yii::app()->user->setFlash('save',"La voiture a été enregistrée avec succes!");

            $this->redirect(array('admin'));

        }

    }
```

please can someone help ?

Answer (score 0):

What does `Yii::app()->params['webroot']` equal to in your case?

According to the error text, it refers to URL, but it has to be path on the server https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/master/framework/web/CUploadedFile.php#L188

Try to use `Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot')` instead.

Comment: the probleme is that " Yii::app()->params['webroot'] " returns my webroot path : http://wmtunisia.com/tamtamtravel.tn/upload/

Comment: according to error message, `Yii::app()->params['webroot']` is `wmtunisia.com/tamtamtravel.tn/upload`. BUT... it should be server path(not url), something like this `/var/www/.../host/upload`.

Comment: reconfigure `params['webroot']` or use `Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot')`

Comment: i tried with Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot') and the error no such file or directory appeared know you if i do fix the alias into the params file or in the controller ?

Comment: doesn't php error say which "file or directory" doesn't exist? you should see the genereted string(path). `Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot')` returns path wihtout trailing slash(/var/www/.../host/upload`), but this line expects `$rep = Yii::app()->params['webroot'].'upload/';` to see it(last slash). So, the proper line will be `$rep = Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/upload/';`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the great example of file upload:

> http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/2/how-to-upload-a-file-using-a-model/

First declare an attribute to store the file name in the model class (either a form model or an active record model). Also declare a file validation rule for this attribute to ensure a file is uploaded with specific extension name.